# Convert a Scala Buffer to Java ArrayList

Tags: java, scala, scala-2.8

In my Scala function, i'm traversing a Java ArrayCollection, extracting specific elements which should form a new collection. At the end, it has to be a Java-ArrayList again, because i'm interacting with a Java Framework.
My Code:

```
// to make scala-style iterating over arraylist possible
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

// ArrayList contains elements of this type:
class Subscription(val subscriber:User, val sender:User)

// I'm getting this list from Java:
val jArrayList = new ArrayList[Subscription]
// Buffer:scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[User]
val buffer = for (val subscription <- jArrayList ) yield subscription.sender
```

How can i convert the Buffer to an ArrayList[User]? Or shouldn't i use yield here?

Comment: This is a super old thread, but for anyone looking to do the same -- the accepted answer here now deprecated. Use `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters` instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to convert it back by specifying what type you'd like `buffer` to be (`JavaConversions` should be brought into play automatically when the type you're trying to get and the one you have are incompatible):

```
val buffer: java.util.List[User] =
  for (val subscription <- jArrayList ) yield subscription.sender
```

Alternatively you can call the conversion from `JavaConversions` explicitly if you want to make it clear what you're doing:

```
val buffer = asList( for ( ... ) ) // buffer should have type "java.util.List[User]"
```

Neither of these actually produce an `ArrayList`; rather, they create a generic `List`, but it's generally bad practice to specify collection types directly. If you must have an `ArrayList`, pass your `List` to the constructor of `ArrayList` which takes a `Collection`:

```
new ArrayList( buffer )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the buffer in the ArrayList constructor to create a new java ArrayList:

```
var newArray = new ArrayList[Int] (buffer)
```

Comment: This would probably work due to the fact that it will be converted implicitly to a java.util.List. Good stuff, although sometimes you really don't need an ArrayList rather than just a List.

Answer (score 1):

When one uses for comprehensions, the underlying code uses `map`, `flatMap`, `foreach`, `filter` or `withFilter` -- see related questions. In this particular example, that code would be equivalent to `jArrayList.map(_.sender)`, and `map` produces new collections (I'm ignoring the implicit conversion here to keep it simple).

What happens here that is perhaps unintuitive, and perhaps could be improved on, is that `ArrayList` does not implement `map`. The implicit conversion gives you a `Buffer` instead, and a `map` on a `Buffer` returns a `Buffer`.

Granted, the `Buffer` on `JavaConversions` preserves the underlying collection, the `ArrayList`, as the backing store. The newly created `Buffer`, on the other hand, won't be based on that, but on one of Scala's own collections.

You could always do this, though:

```
val buffer = (for (val subscription <- jArrayList ) yield subscription.sender).asList
```